# Using Browsersync via a Gulp Task with DDEV-local

Tags: gulp, browser-sync, ddev, gulp-browser-sync

I am using DDEV as my local hosting environment, and many of my projects implement front end automation via Gulp. [Browsersync](https://browsersync.io/) is a major component to our front end set-up, and requires ports to be exposed by the DDEV container to the host machine. The problem at hand is two fold, what is the best way to expose a port to the host machine from the container, and what is the best set-up for a Browser-Sync Gulp task in a DDEV environment?

Comment: I'm using the same automation with ddev, but the key feature of browsersync doesn't work for me, the auto reload if changing files. I'm working on Mac and if I'm saving a file, the gulp watchers don't "see" the changes and so there is no reload. Do you have a solution for this problem?

Comment: @emjay were you able to work this out? If not my first suggestion would be to ensure you are using Polling in your watch tasks: `{ usePolling: true, interval: 1000 }`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Exposing the Necessary Ports

Part one of this situation requires using a Docker Compose file to expose your container's port to the hose machine. Based on [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62648434/using-docker-compose-to-expose-ddev-web-container-ports-to-host-machine/62648435#62648435) you need to create a `docker-compose.browsersync.yaml` file in your `.ddev` directory.

An example of that file for Browser-Sync would be as follows:

```yaml
# Override the web container's standard HTTP_EXPOSE and HTTPS_EXPOSE
# This is to expose the browsersync port.
version: '3.6'
services:
  web:
    # ports are a list of exposed *container* ports
    expose:
      - '3000'
    environment:
      - HTTP_EXPOSE=${DDEV_ROUTER_HTTP_PORT}:80,${DDEV_MAILHOG_PORT}:8025,3001:3000
      - HTTPS_EXPOSE=${DDEV_ROUTER_HTTPS_PORT}:80,${DDEV_MAILHOG_HTTPS_PORT}:8025,3000:3000
```

We expose Port 3000 here because it is the default for Browser-Sync, but could be updated to reflect the needs of your projects.

**Note:** After adding this file to your `.ddev` directory you should restart your ddev project.

For more information on defining new services with docker compose, [read the DDEV docs](https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/stable/users/extend/custom-compose-files/#defining-an-additional-service-with-docker-compose).

### Setting-Up Browser-Sync in Gulp

This assumes you have a working `gulpfile.js` ready to do with your other required packages included already. If you're not fully familiar with Browser-Sync and Gulp, please refer to [their docs](https://www.browsersync.io/docs/gulp) for full details.

```js
const browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();

/*
* Set 'url' (the host and proxy hostnames) to match the canonical url of your ddev project.
* Do not include the http/s protocol in the url. The ddev-router will route the
* host machine's request to the appropriate protocol.
* 
* ex: yoursite.ddev.site
*/
const url = 'yoursite.ddev.site';

/*
* This function only includes the most basic browser-sync settings needed
* to get a watch server running. Please refer to the browser-sync docs for other
* available options.
*/
const startServer = function (done) {
    // Initialize BrowserSync
    browserSync.init({
        proxy: url,
        host: url,
        port: 3000,
    });
    done();
};

exports.startServer = startServer;
```

You can test this using `gulp startServer` after initial set-up. Gulp will output a `http` as the External URL for testing. However thanks to the ddev-router it can be accessed via `http` or `https`.

Comment: I walked through this, made a couple of minor edits, and after doing it all got it working. The only problem is that  I understand is that the `gulp startServer` outputs an http URL for an https site. This could be changed in the HTTP_EXPOSE and HTTPS_EXPOSE to flip the ports they expose, or you could just edit to add a warning about the URL that gulp outputs.

Comment: You're correct @rfay that was an oversight on my part. I missed it because of Firefox enforcing https everywhere. There is an option for browser-sync as well to use https. I've update the answer to reflect that option.

Comment: Update: after further testing. The `https` option in the `browser-sync.init()` does not seem to play nicely with the ddev-router. However excluding it allows for the browser-sync server to launch correctly, and it can be accessed on the host machine via http or https.

Answer (score 1):

### Exposing Port 3000 for HTTP & HTTPS for BrowserSync

piggy-backing on the answer from [@TXChetG](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1408117/txchetg) and the [answer from @Mario Hernandez](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62648434/using-docker-compose-to-expose-ddev-web-container-ports-to-host-machine/62648435#62648435)

create a file called "docker-compose.browsersync.yaml" inside your hidden /.ddev/ config folder with code below, tabbed properly (which is very important), then run the command "ddev restart"

```
# Override the web container standard HTTP_EXPOSE and HTTPS_EXPOSE
# This is to expose the browsersync port.
version: '3.6'
services:
  web:
    # ports are a list of exposed *container* ports
    expose:
      - '3000'
    environment:
      - HTTP_EXPOSE=${DDEV_ROUTER_HTTP_PORT}:80
      - HTTPS_EXPOSE=${DDEV_ROUTER_HTTPS_PORT}:80
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are a mac user and browsersync still doesn't work with the above solution, you might need to update your /etc/hosts file as I had to.

You can check more details in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32818408/18631192).

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to run browsersync from *within* the container.  I updated my local system and ran browsersync *locally*

I used Stephen's solution elsewhere on this page (https://stackoverflow.com/a/70190271/18779 for quick reference).

I am running a Mac so I also did the following:

- Upgrade homebrew
- Use brew to install nvm
- Use nvm to install node 12 (I had to try a few versions to eliminate errors.  12 worked for me.
- Use npm to rebuild node-sass.  I got sass errors before I did this.
- run browsersync.  I am using Drupal and Radix subtheme so, for me, that was `cd [subtheme dir]` and `npm run watch`

Answer (score 0):

The above tips and from other posts like:

[Using Docker Compose to expose DDEV web container ports to host machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62648434/using-docker-compose-to-expose-ddev-web-container-ports-to-host-machine)

[Chrome can't open localhost:3000 with Gulp / BrowserSync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32171725/chrome-cant-open-localhost3000-with-gulp-browsersync)

may be fine for a website on the HTTP protocol but not for one on HTTPS.

Specifically, I am testing a CMS installation in DDEV, with secure URLs in the Frontend/Backend. After running the `ddev start` command, it is displayed that I access it in the browser using `https://myproject.ddev.site` or `https://127.0.0.1:62751` (the socket changes with each run of DDEV).

I didn't install `drud/ddev-browsersync` package because it doesn't proxy to HTTPS, in my case it didn't help me at all.

In a directory I created the gulpfile.js file to perform complex tasks on scss, js, css, html files. In order not to manually reload the page in the browser, I obviously need BrowserSync. The only configuration that worked is the following:

```
const browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();

function startServer () {

    browserSync.init({
      proxy: 'https://127.0.0.1:62751',
    });
};

exports.startServer = startServer;
```

When I run the `gulp startServer` command, first `https://localhost:3002` is displayed in the address bar, then after a while it redirects to `https://myproject.ddev.site`. From this moment on, I make any changes to the files.

The only issue I have is that after each run of the `ddev start` command I have to manually change the port in the line `https://127.0.0.1:XXXXX`. If DDEV provides this value I could use it and then the issue is solved.